# Android Togglebutton displays an unwanted icon

Tags: android, android-studio, android-theme, android-styles, android-togglebutton

When removing android:theme tag from AndroidManifest.xml a weird icon appears in Togglebuttons

```
<ToggleButton
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```

In design screen nothing appears but on device it displays an icon similar to this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [opensuse.org](https://en.opensuse.org/images/thumb/8/80/Icon-forbidden.png/120px-Icon-forbidden.png))</sub>

If I add a background, the icon appears inside the background and before the text.

It happens when removing android:theme tag.

It looks like a default style for ToggleButton but I don't find any way to get rid of it.

I would like some way to override this no theme behaviour of ToggleButtons by declaring a style for ToggleButton or using a theme that only affects ToggleButton.
If not I will have to settle with using regular buttons or custom widget.

Comment: I suppose this image exists in your `drawable` folder?

Comment: No, I believe it might be in the sdk somewhere.

Comment: That's odd. Give me a minute

Comment: Is this the only place in your code where you mention the `ToggleButton`? You don't do anything with it programmatically?

Comment: I change its visibility and checked state. But then I tried making an empty togglebutton with no code attached, id or anything which is the xml code I pasted in the question and it still showed the circle icon.

Comment: I've tried to replicate your problem, but I don't get the image? So I don't really know what's happening with your toggle button? Could you try to create a new project and add a toggle button to see what it looks like?

Comment: Hmph. on a new blank project it doesn't happen. I'm trying to remove libraries and dependencies to find out what is causing it

Comment: So something must be wrong with your current project - please report back your progress

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87898/discussion-between-origence-and-detilium).